# aws amplify - process.env.API_KEY is undefined

Tags: next.js, environment-variables, aws-amplify

I add to amplify build setting:

[image: build settings]

I also add to amplify.yml in the code

```
version: 0.1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run export
        **- REACT_APP_ENV_API=${REACT_APP_ENV_API}**
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .next
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

I add to the amplify env vars my react env var here:
[image: amplify env vars]

and still I get undefined when I trying to use process.env.REACT_APP_ENV_API.

Comment: Are you trying to access `process.env.REACT_APP_ENV_API` on the client-side? In Next.js, to expose an environment variable to the browser you need to prefix it with `NEXT_PUBLIC_`, see https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser.

Answer (score 3):

I got it working by first adding the environment variables to the AWS Amplify console via App Settings > Environment Variables.

Then I went to App Settings > Build Settings and modified the `amplify.yml` config file to include the variable definitions.

E.g:

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - yarn install
    build:
      commands:
        - echo "GITHUB_CLIENT_ID=$GITHUB_CLIENT_ID" >> .env
        - echo "GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET=$GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET" >> .env
        - echo "NEXTAUTH_URL=$NEXTAUTH_URL" >> .env
        - echo "NEXTAUTH_SECRET=$NEXTAUTH_SECRET" >> .env
        - yarn run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .next
    files:
      - "**/*"
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `export`:

```yaml
- export REACT_APP_ENV_API=${REACT_APP_ENV_API}
```

Also, as per Julio's comments, if you're using Next.js, do make sure you're doing as documented for exposing env vars to the browser: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser